# ttf font file not working on local website

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm on a mac and I've downloaded a font in ttf format that i want to use on my local website. I've added it as a font-face and added it to a class:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'The Amazing Spider-Man';
  src: url('/fonts/The Amazing Spider-Man.ttf');
}
.pageTitle{

  font-family: 'The Amazing Spider-Man';
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

My folder structure is:

```
css
  style.css
  -fonts
    The Amazing Spider-Man.ttf
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I've installed the font and I copied the file name and pasted it everywhere so I don't know why it wouldn't be working when applied like so:

```
<p class="pageTitle">test</p>
```

Comment: Maybe the spaces causes problem. Please check the spaces on the filename and font name

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I renamed it 'spider_man' and replaced it everywhere but still nothing

Comment: Rename the file name to remove spaces but KEEP The spaces in the `font-family` name. The "name" is embedded in the font as a reference for when its called.

Comment: You might have the name wrong too. Install the font in your system then open a program with a font list like word or photoshop. Call the font by using the name that is displayed in the system font picker menu.